# Can i host and stream a website off one raspberry pi?

Tags: web-server

I am looking to create an active score board for my sports club clubhouse where captains upload the scores,potentially via an app, and it appears on a monitor at the clubhouse.
My question is... would I be able to host the website they upload the scores to and stream that website to a monitor off one raspberry pi or would I need two?

Comment: why not? ... linux is a very powerful OS

Answer (score 2):

One Raspberry Pi is sufficient for the tasks you mention.